# Does Mac OS X Server incorporate all the capabilities of Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I'm thinking about purchasing a copy of Snow Leopard Server as I'm setting up a web/mail server pretty soon. I also want to dig into things that the server has to offer. I'm looking into maybe getting a trial copy first (if possible). However, since I only have one personal Mac, I'm concerned with compatibility issues. Can Snow Leopard Server do anything (/run anything) that Snow Leopard would?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get a trial here: http://seminars.apple.com/contactme/SnowLeopardServerEvaluation/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about the Snow Leopard situation (haven't upgraded yet, until Apple fixed a few early issues), but that was indeed the situation for Leopard, and Tiger before it; I'd be amazed if that got broken in this latest release.

Answer (score 1):

OS X server is pretty much the same as OS X Client. The only difference is that Server gives you a whole bunch of server applications and management tools to allow you to run a network of Macs.

There may be some minor tuning of system parameters and such, but other than the additional software it's basically the same.

Paul